# closure-to-parameters transform for JavaScript (babel, traceur, etc)

Tags: javascript, babeljs, code-generation

Looking for a (babel, traceur, etc) transform that eliminates closures (turns closed-over variables into explicit parameters)

Example:

```js
function original(){
    var sum = 0;
    var add = 1;
    var param = 2;
    var inc = (p2) => { ++add; return add + p2; }
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        sum += inc(param);
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

Output option 1:

```js
// ===== GENERATED BELOW
function inc_noclo(locals, p2) {
    ++locals.add; return locals.add + p2;
}

function rewritten1(){ 
    var sum = 0;
    var locals = {add: 1}
    var param = 2;
    var inc = inc_noclo.bind(null, locals);
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        sum += inc(param);
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

Output option 2:

```js
function inc_noclo(locals, p2) {
    ++locals.add; return locals.add + p2;
}

function rewritten2(){ 
    var sum = 0;
    var locals = {add: 1}
    var param = 2;
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        sum += inc_noclo(locals, param);
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

Known implementations that are NOT suitable:

- special case when no variables are closed over: [codemix/babel-plugin-closure-elimination](https://github.com/codemix/babel-plugin-closure-elimination)
- a bit better: https://github.com/flexport/reflective-bind

Suitable but not for JS:

- in [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) there's a transform class like this, but it's too tied to Roslyn specifics

Comment: What do you need this for? Btw, `bind` is hardly better than a closure and also messes up `this`.

Comment: I don't think this is generally possible if the closure is being passed around to functions that cannot be transformed as well. Your example (where `inc` also could be trivially inlined) is a bit too simple.

Comment: @Bergi i'm trying to target an embedded platform where the JS engine is awfully slow with closures and there's no debugger so inspecting closures like Chrome does is impossible (but transforming 100% of code including stdlib is fine)

Comment: also it would help immensely with transpiling JS to platforms where there's no closures at all, of course :)

Comment: You would need to transform every single function definition into an object with a `.scope` property and a `.call` method, so that you are able pass them around together. Then transform every call (inluding native ones) into `functionObject.call(receiver, ...arguments)`. Also deal with hoisting as the objects won't be able to replace declarations easily. But all of this is what the engine should be doing internally already, and I cannot believe that it would become faster by doing that. Rather optimise the engine itself if it has performance problems.

Comment: yep that's exactly what Roslyn does, except it does not need to lift every callsite from f() to o.f() because it's easier to determine the callsite type in CIL and specialize it, so there's less of a performance hit. Also you're right that if i'm to go without dataflow analysis I'll need to specialize every single one, I just hoped I can side-step it with passing closure scope as the last parameter and inserting a check to distinguish it from omitted optional parameters.

Comment: Using two variables (like `inc_locals` and `inc_fn`) for functions everywhere (including making two parameter for every function to be passed to a call) might work and be a good step on the way to optimise the object creation overhead away - except for those parts of the code where you can't decide whether a variable is typed as a function or not. To make this work generally even in all edge cases, I think it would come down to a complete interpreter - and you'll rather want to work at optimising the embedded interpreter that you already have.

Comment: Yep, something like that. I greatly appreciate this discussion, thanks a lot! Also if we are to follow StackOverflow protocols, you can copy-paste your last 2 comments as an answer, and I'll accept it, as I have a much better picture now :) Or maybe we can leave it open, and continue via some more discussion-friendly medium (chat? mailing list? forum? lambda the ultimate? etc)